# How To Access An Array In A NetBeans Class From A JSP Page?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, javabeans

I have a Java class that has an array in it. I need to iterate over the array in the JSP page. How is that done?

The class is:

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class voteDB implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public sesion[] Users = new sesion[4];{
        Users[0] = new sesion("John", 1234);
        Users[1] = new sesion("Paul", 2345);
        Users[2] = new sesion("Ringo", 3456);
        Users[3] = new sesion("George", 4567);
    }
}
```

and the JSP page is:

```
<%@page import="beans.voteDB"%>
<%@page import="beans.sesion"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bienvenido!</h1>

<%
    String UsuarioIn="", ContrasenaIn="";
    if (request.getParameter("usuario") != null){
        UsuarioIn = request.getParameter("usuario");
    }
    if (request.getParameter("contrsena") != null){
        ContrasenaIn = request.getParameter("contrsena");
    }

%>
<jsp:useBean id="sesionActual" class="beans.sesion" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="sesionActual" property="usuario" value="<%=UsuarioIn %>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="sesionActual" property="contrasena" value="<%=ContrasenaIn %>"/>


<table>
    <tr><td>Nombre: </td><td><jsp:getProperty property="usuario" name="sesionActual"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Contrseña: </td><td><jsp:getProperty property="contrasena" name="sesionActual"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your IDE plays no role in this.

Comment: What on Earth is a NetBeans Class ??

Comment: what is netbeans class??

Comment: Can you show us your code please.

Comment: I am using Eclipse to edit the code, and a class in Java. Does that help? Yes, my code is:
this is the class:

Comment: @user3170030 as Sotirios Delimanolis said, your IDE has NO role to play in this.

Comment: Ok - I updated my question to include the code. Thank you all very much for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

1. Though it still compiles, one is recommended to always follow the [Java coding (naming) conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) ([full versions here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)).
2. I'd be surprised if the *voteDB* class survived in any way: be it in the IDE w/o showing up any error or even compiles at all; my guess is you might have a background w/ another programming language.
3. Here comes the productive words for the question asked: using [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Collection.html) should do the tricks, please refer to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)!

Here's my example, w/ a few adjustments to the code you provided:

```
package beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VoteDB {

    private List<Sesion> sesions;

    public VoteDB() {
        this.sesions = new ArrayList<>(); // Forgot the definition (class initialization) the first time I typed this answer, which would throw NullPointerException
        this.sesions.add(new Sesion("John", 1234));
        this.sesions.add(new Sesion("Paul", 2345));
        this.sesions.add(new Sesion("Ringo", 3456));
        this.sesions.add(new Sesion("George", 4567));
    }

    public List<Sesion> getSesions() {
        return sesions;
    }

    public void setSesions(List<Sesion> sesions) {
        this.sesions = sesions;
    }
}
```

Assuming the *Sesion* class is in the same package like the *VoteDB* class:

```
package beans;

public class Sesion {

    private String key;

    private Integer value;

    public Sesion(String key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And in the .jsp:

```
<%@page import="beans.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%
    VoteDB voteDB = new VoteDB();

    for (Sesion sesion : voteDB.getSesions()) {
        out.println(sesion.getKey() + ":" + sesion.getValue());
    }
%>
```

There are certainly other ways to archive your goals/needs, mine is just one of those while trying to solve it in a more Java-like fashion.

Comment: Wow, THAT is an excellent answer!

I've tried doing this, and while it seems spot on for what I need, I now get an HTTP error 500, that says that this line    <jsp:useBean id="sesionActual" class="beans.Sesion" scope="session"/>
is invalid:
security.jsp (line: 26, column: 1) The value for the useBean class attribute beans.Sesion is invalid.
Why is that?